# Jupyter theorem environment

Tags: math, jupyter-notebook

I am new to jupyter notebooks, and I am trying to use juptyter notebooks to create lecture notes. I can figure out how to do equation numbering, but I don't know how to enable a theorem-proof environment like in latex. I looked online, but they all describe latex commands or at best equation numbering. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Good luck with your endeavour. I've used Jupyter Notebooks to teach math classes too, but I only used Markdown for the page layout, and LaTeX for the math formula, so I don't have an answer for you. Google gives me this: https://notebook.community/andyneff/IPython-notebook-extensions/nbextensions/usability/latex_envs/doc/latex/latex_env_doc-ltx which appears to be an extension to Jupyter that can handle environments such as theorems. If you do find an answer yourself, please post it here as I'm sure other people (and myself) will be interested.

Comment: Very interesting question, although a how-to for this particular system might find a more informed audience in a project-specific forum such as https://discourse.jupyter.org/ .

Comment: Thanks. I've posted on discourse.jupyter.org. Now, twiddling thumbs. I'll post a reply if and when I get it here.